# Add multiple menu item

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created one menu for file upload to Google drive using the following function. Here the menu name is 'Attach PO' , if I want to add another menu named 'Attach GRN' with same logic which will help me uploading files into google drive but in separate folder , how do I add this.  Now if I copy the function and make a new copy and set the menu name to a new one , it does not work, I can only see one menu item.

Appscript:

```
Folder_Id = '1hJ8OGGsSBApnCpUYCqaQTktRbcOd04aK'


function onOpen(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var menuEntries = [];
  menuEntries.push({name: "File", functionName: "doGet"});
  ss.addMenu("Attach PO", menuEntries);
}


function upload(obj) {
  var file = DriveApp.getFolderById(Folder_Id).createFile(obj.upload);
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var File_name = file.getName()
  var value = 'hyperlink("' + file.getUrl() + '";"' + File_name + '")'
  
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var selection = activeSheet.getSelection();
  var cell = selection.getCurrentCell()
  cell.setFormula(value)
  
  return {
    fileId: file.getId(),
    mimeType: file.getMimeType(),
    fileName: file.getName(),
  };
}

function doGet(e) {
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var selection = activeSheet.getSelection();
  var cell = selection.getCurrentCell();
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('upload');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Upload File');
}
```

Html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <form> <!-- Modified -->
    <div id="progress" ></div>
    <input type="file" name="upload" id="file">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" class="action" onclick="form_data(this.parentNode)" >
    <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
  </form>
  <script>
    function form_data(obj){ // Modified
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(closeIt).upload(obj);
    };
    function closeIt(e){ // Modified
      console.log(e);
      google.script.host.close();
    };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make them submenus

Answer (score 1):

First you have in mind is that Google Apps Script uses JavaScript so every function name should be unique.

Second thing is that `onOpen` is a reserved function name for an on open simple trigger.

Third thing is that you could find a complete example of a custom menu with multiple item on the official guides, more specifically on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('my menu') {
  .addItem('caption','funcname')
  .addSubMenu(SpreadsheetApp.createMenu('sub 1')
  .addItem('caption','funcname'))
  .addToUi();
```